# server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'testusername\'\' at line 1' }

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

so I try to save on a sql database some data (users data) and I have this error. I try to put some quotes etc.

But when I try I get this error can you help me please ?

Thanks

the error : 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''testusername'' at line 1' }

The log :

```
testusername

test

testname1

testpassword

test@gmail.com

1f134419-14c5-439e-95a5-a46d675085bd


Connected!

--> ComQueryPacket

ComQueryPacket {

command: 3,

sql: 'INSERT INTO utilisateurs (nomutilisateur, Nomfamille, prenomutilisateur, mdp, email, setup, token) VALUES 'testusername'' }


<-- ErrorPacket

ErrorPacket {

fieldCount: 255,

errno: 1064,

sqlStateMarker: '#',

sqlState: '42000',

message: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''testusername'' at line 1' }


/home/gaspard/Bureau/Gaspard/inscription/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80

throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors

^


TypeError: this._callback.apply is not a function


and The source code (I can't show all the code because is confidential)


    var pseudo = req.body.pseudo

console.log(pseudo);

var data2 = req.body.nomfamille


console.log(data2);


var data3 =  req.body.prenom


console.log(data3);

var data5 = req.body.mdp


console.log(data5);


var data6 = req.body.email


console.log(data6);

var token = uuid.v4();


   var setup = setup



   console.log(token);



  con.connect(function(err) {

if (err) throw err;

console.log("Connected!");

var sql = 'INSERT INTO utilisateurs (nomutilisateur, Nomfamille, prenomutilisateur, mdp, email, setup, token) VALUES ?';

con.query(sql,[pseudo],[data2],[data3],[data5],[setup],[token], function (err, result) {

console.log(err);


I try this code :


con.query('INSERT INTO utilisateurs (nomutilisateur, Nomfamille, prenomutilisateur, mdp, email, setup, token) VALUES ?', pseudo,data2,data3,data5,data6,token,setup, function(err, result) {


and :


con.query('INSERT INTO utilisateurs (nomutilisateur, Nomfamille, prenomutilisateur, mdp, email, setup, token) VALUES ?', '"+pseudo"','"+data2"','"+data3"','"+data5"','"+data6"','"+token"','"+setup"', function(err, result) {
```

I use the latest version of node sql , node js and npm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not wrapping your `VALUES` in parentheses

```
INSERT INTO utilisateurs
  (nomutilisateur, Nomfamille, prenomutilisateur, mdp, email, setup, token) 
VALUES 'testusername'
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO utilisateurs
  (nomutilisateur, Nomfamille, prenomutilisateur, mdp, email, setup, token)
VALUES ('testusername')
```

You also probably want to specify all values from your insert statement clause. Otherwise it will default to `NULL` and may not work depending on whether there are column constraints on the table.

References

- http://www.dofactory.com/sql/insert